# Визуальный редактор Markdown в комментариях

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Всем привет!

Какими средствами можно запилить редактор текста в комментариях\постах? Есть ли какие-нибудь гемы для этой затеи?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне нравится [WMD](http://rubygems.org/gems/wmd-rails)

Comment: на 4ые рельсы встает?

upd. вижу что встает)